# Scrollable Composite - auto resize - swt

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

I have a Application Window using a Scrollable Composite.

Inside scrollable composite we could have N composites (accordingly database data).

How could I detected the size of children's composites to set the correct height?

```
/**
 * Create contents of the application window.
 * @param parent
 */
@Override
protected Control createContents(Composite parent) {

    final ScrolledComposite sc = new ScrolledComposite(parent, SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.BORDER);
    final Composite containerEditarAtendimento = new Composite(sc, SWT.BORDER);
    containerEditarAtendimento.setSize(800, 630);
    sc.setContent(containerEditarAtendimento);
    sc.setExpandHorizontal(true);
    sc.setExpandVertical(true);
    sc.setMinSize(containerEditarAtendimento.computeSize(820, 480));
    GridLayout gridLayout = new GridLayout(1, false);
    gridLayout.marginTop = 5;
    gridLayout.marginRight = 5;
    gridLayout.marginBottom = 5;
    gridLayout.marginLeft = 5;  
    containerEditarAtendimento.setLayout(gridLayout);
    { // Composite com as informações de atendimento.
        EditarAtendimentoComposite editarAtendimentoComposite = new EditarAtendimentoComposite(containerEditarAtendimento, SWT.BORDER);
        GridData gd_editarAtendimentoComposite = new GridData(GridData.FILL, GridData.FILL, true, false);
        gd_editarAtendimentoComposite.heightHint = 249;
        editarAtendimentoComposite.setLayoutData(gd_editarAtendimentoComposite);
    }
    {
        Composite compoExterno = formToolkit.createComposite(containerEditarAtendimento, SWT.BORDER);
        compoExterno.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, false));
        GridData gd_compoExterno = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.TOP, true, false, 1, 1);
        gd_compoExterno.heightHint = 153;
        compoExterno.setLayoutData(gd_compoExterno);

        formToolkit.paintBordersFor(compoExterno);
        {
            Label lblAnexos = formToolkit.createLabel(compoExterno, getLabel("label.anexos"), SWT.NONE);
        }
        new Label(compoExterno, SWT.NONE);
        {
            Button btnAddAnexo = formToolkit.createButton(compoExterno, getLabel("label.incluiranexo"), SWT.NONE);
            btnAddAnexo.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.RIGHT, SWT.CENTER, false, false, 1, 1));
        }
        { // Composite com os anexos
            AnexosComposite anexosComposite = new AnexosComposite(compoExterno,SWT.BORDER);
            GridData gd_anexosComposite = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.TOP, true, false, 3, 1);
            gd_anexosComposite.heightHint = 107;
            anexosComposite.setLayoutData(gd_anexosComposite);

        }

    }
    {   // Composite onde ficará o expandable do diagnostico
        PlanoAcaoExternoComposite planoAcaoComposite = new PlanoAcaoExternoComposite(containerEditarAtendimento, SWT.BORDER);
        GridData gd_planoAcaoComposite = new GridData(GridData.FILL, GridData.FILL, true, false);
        planoAcaoComposite.setLayoutData(gd_planoAcaoComposite);
        formToolkit.adapt(planoAcaoComposite);
        formToolkit.paintBordersFor(planoAcaoComposite);
        planoAcaoComposite.layout(true, true);
        log.info("Height: {}",planoAcaoComposite.getClientArea().height);
        log.info("getSize().x: {}",planoAcaoComposite.getSize().x);
        log.info("getSize().y: {}",planoAcaoComposite.getSize().y);
        sc.setMinSize(containerEditarAtendimento.computeSize(800, 2000)); // HOW TO DYNAMICALLY SET HEIGHT?
    }
    sc.layout(true,true);
    return containerEditarAtendimento;
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The following code will make the `ScrolledComposite` set the `minSize` according to the content and show the scrollbars if you decrease the size of the `Shell`:

```
ScrolledComposite sc = new ScrolledComposite(content, SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.BORDER);

Composite composite = new Composite(sc, SWT.NONE);
composite.setLayout(new FillLayout(SWT.VERTICAL));

new Label(composite, SWT.NONE).setText("1111");
new Label(composite, SWT.NONE).setText("2222");
new Label(composite, SWT.NONE).setText("3333");
new Label(composite, SWT.NONE).setText("4444");
new Label(composite, SWT.NONE).setText("5555");
new Label(composite, SWT.NONE).setText("6666");
new Label(composite, SWT.NONE).setText("7777");

sc.setContent(composite);
sc.setExpandHorizontal(true);
sc.setExpandVertical(true);
sc.setMinSize(composite.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT));
```

Comment: @davidfdr Glad I could help. Please consider upvoting the answer as well.

Comment: Sure! But I need 15 reputation. I am new to stack overflow!

Answer (score 0):

Content of a scrolled window needs to be there, and fixed 
setting grabExxcessHorizontalspace and vertical to "true".

```
 public class SWT_Composite_scroll_test {

    private static Display display;
    private Font font;
    public static FontData[] fontdata, tmp;
    public static FontData fd;
    public String name;
    public static String fontname;
    public String DIALOG;
    public String DIALOGINPUT;
    public String MONOSPACED;
    public String SERIF;
    public String SANS_SERIF;
    public String LUCIDIA;
    public int size, data, style, Plain=0, Bold=1, Italic=2;
    Object[] font_objects;
    String[] font_names, styletype = {"Normal","Bold","Italic"};
    SWT_Composite_scroll_test(){}

    public static void main(String args[]){
            display = new Display();
            tmp = new FontData[Display.getDefault().getFontList(null, false).length];
            for(int j=0;j<tmp.length;j++){ tmp[j] = Display.getDefault().getFontList(null, false)[j];}
            System.out.println("System fonts loaded.");
            SWT_Composite_scroll_test  c = new SWT_Composite_scroll_test ();
            c.getFonts();

    }

private void getFonts(){

        final Shell fontdialog = new Shell(display,SWT.BORDER|SWT.PRIMARY_MODAL|SWT.RESIZE|SWT.CLOSE);
                            fontdialog.setText(Parent.getResourceString("Set fonts for system. "));
                            /* Create 3 unevenly columns in dialog*/
                            fontdialog.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,false));
                    Label label = new Label(fontdialog,SWT.FILL);
                            /* set label 3 columns wide, grab all horizontal space, but vertical just one row.*/
                            label.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL,SWT.FILL,true,false,3,1));
                            label.setText("Dit is een text.");

            final Composite tablecontainer = new Composite(fontdialog,SWT.BORDER|SWT.V_SCROLL|SWT.H_SCROLL);
                    /* Design tablecontainer layout, no spacing to prevent white spots when content is scrolled.*/
                    GridLayout gl = new GridLayout();
                    gl.marginLeft = 0;
                    gl.marginHeight = 0;
                    gl.marginBottom = 0;
                    gl.marginRight = 0;
                    gl.verticalSpacing = 0;
                    gl.horizontalSpacing = 0;
                    tablecontainer.setLayout(gl);
                    /* Completely fill and grab all vertical space for content, one column and one row.*/
                    final GridData tblgd = new GridData(SWT.FILL,SWT.FILL,true,true,1,1);
                    tablecontainer.setLayoutData(tblgd);

                    final Composite tableheader = new Composite(tablecontainer,SWT.FILL|SWT.INHERIT_DEFAULT);
                            tableheader.setFont(Configuration.default_font);
                            RowLayout rlb = new RowLayout();
                            rlb.pack = false;//<-------------(all elements are the same size).
                            rlb.justify = true;// <------- (elements are spread across the available space).
                            tableheader.setLayout(rlb);
                            tableheader.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL,SWT.FILL,false,false));
                        final Label subjectcolumn = new Label(tableheader,SWT.FILL|SWT.LEFT|SWT.INHERIT_DEFAULT);
                                    subjectcolumn.setText(Parent.getResourceString("Subject name"));
                        final Label namecolumn = new Label(tableheader,SWT.FILL|SWT.CENTER|SWT.INHERIT_DEFAULT);
                                    namecolumn.setText(Parent.getResourceString("Font name"));  
                        final Label stylecolumn = new Label(tableheader,SWT.FILL|SWT.CENTER|SWT.INHERIT_DEFAULT);
                                    stylecolumn.setText(Parent.getResourceString("Font style"));
                        final Label sizecolumn = new Label(tableheader,SWT.FILL|SWT.CENTER|SWT.INHERIT_DEFAULT);
                                    sizecolumn.setText(Parent.getResourceString("Font size"));

                    final Composite table = new Composite(tablecontainer,SWT.INHERIT_DEFAULT);
                                    RowLayout tbfl = new RowLayout();
                                    tbfl.type = SWT.VERTICAL;
                                    table.setLayout(tbfl);  
                                    table.setFont(Configuration.default_font);  
                                    final GridData tbge = new GridData(SWT.FILL,SWT.FILL,false,false);
                                    table.setLayoutData(tbge);

                                    Group testgroup = new Group(table, SWT.FILL);
                                    testgroup.setLayout(new GridLayout());
                                    new Label(testgroup,SWT.INHERIT_DEFAULT).setText("This is a test label in side the scrolled content.");
                                    new Label(testgroup,SWT.INHERIT_DEFAULT).setText("This is a test label in side the scrolled content.");
                                    Button resize = new Button(testgroup, SWT.PUSH);
                                    resize.setText("Rezise bigger");
                                    resize.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {                  
                                                        tablecontainer.setSize(tablecontainer.getSize().x<<1,tablecontainer.getSize().y<<1); /* resize scrolled composite setting data height x 2;*/
                                                        tablecontainer.layout();
                                                      }
                                                    }); 
                                    Button resizeS = new Button(testgroup, SWT.PUSH);
                                    resizeS.setText("Rezise smaller");
                                    resizeS.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {                  
                                                        tablecontainer.setSize(tablecontainer.getSize().x>>1,tablecontainer.getSize().y>>1); /* resize scrolled composite setting data height x 2;*/
                                                        tablecontainer.layout();
                                                      }
                                                    }); 
                        for(int i=0;i<tmp.length;i++){  
                            Composite tablerow = new Composite(table,SWT.FILL);                         
                                            RowLayout rlc = new RowLayout();
                                            rlc.center = true;
                                            rlc.fill = true;
                                            rlc.pack = false;//<-------------(all elements are the same size).
                                            rlc.wrap = false;// <------- (clips if not enough space). [ This one makes content invisible when out of sight. ]
                                            rlc.marginLeft = 1;
                                            rlc.marginHeight = 1;
                                            rlc.marginBottom = 1;
                                            rlc.marginRight = 1;
                                            rlc.marginWidth = 1;
                                            rlc.spacing = 1;
                                            tablerow.setLayout(rlc);
                                            new Label(tablerow, SWT.INHERIT_DEFAULT).setText(tmp[i].getName());
                    System.out.println(tableheader.getBounds().width+"2: vPage:"+table.getSize().y+" vSelection:"+tablecontainer.getClientArea().y);
                                            final Combo fontcombo = new Combo(tablerow, SWT.RIGHT);                         
                                                fontcombo.setForeground(display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_WHITE));
                                                fontcombo.setBackground(display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_RED));
                    for(int j=0;j<tmp.length;j++){fontcombo.add(""+tmp[j].getName());}
                                                fontcombo.addSelectionListener(new SelectionListener() {
                                                    public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                                                        fd = Display.getDefault().getFontList(null, true)[fontcombo.getSelectionIndex()];       
                                                        }
                                                    @Override
                                                    public void widgetDefaultSelected(SelectionEvent e) {}
                                                    });
                                            final Combo stylecombo = new Combo (tablerow, SWT.INHERIT_DEFAULT);
                                                for(int j=0;j<styletype.length;j++){stylecombo.add(styletype[j]);}
                                                stylecombo.addSelectionListener(new SelectionListener() {
                                                    public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                                                        style = stylecombo.getSelectionIndex();       
                                                        }
                                                    @Override
                                                    public void widgetDefaultSelected(SelectionEvent e) {}
                                                    }); 
                                            final Combo sizecombo = new Combo(tablerow,SWT.RIGHT|SWT.INHERIT_DEFAULT);
                                                for(int j=0;j<28;j++){sizecombo.add(""+j);}
                                                sizecombo.addSelectionListener(new SelectionListener() {
                                                    public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                                                        size = sizecombo.getSelectionIndex();       
                                                        }
                                                    @Override
                                                    public void widgetDefaultSelected(SelectionEvent e) {}
                                                    }); 
                                            }
                final ScrollBar vBar = tablecontainer.getVerticalBar();
                final ScrollBar hBar = tablecontainer.getHorizontalBar();
                        vBar.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener() {
                            @Override
                            public void handleEvent(Event e) {
                                int contentY = table.getSize().y - tableheader.getSize().y;     // total height of the page. [ table ]
                                int windowY = tablecontainer.getSize().y - tableheader.getSize().y;// total height of the window [ tablecontainer ]. 
                                int locationY = vBar.getSelection() - tableheader.getSize().y;  // point where table is in window. 0 = top.
                                int vPageEnd = contentY - windowY;
                                if(locationY >= vPageEnd){ locationY = vPageEnd ;}
                                table.setLocation(5, - locationY);                              // 5 is left margin. 
                                }
                            });
                        hBar.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener() {
                            @Override
                            public void handleEvent(Event e) {      
                                /* Horizontal scrolbar.*/
                                int contentX = table.getSize().x - vBar.getSize().x;                                // total height of the page. [ table ]
                                int windowX = tablecontainer.getSize().x - vBar.getSize().x;                        // total height of the window [ tablecontainer ]. 
                                int locationX = hBar.getSelection();                            // point where table is in window. 0 = top.
                                int hPageEnd = contentX - windowX;
                                if(locationX >= hPageEnd){ locationX = hPageEnd ;}
                                table.setLocation(-locationX+5, tableheader.getSize().y);                               // 5 is left margin. 
                                }
                            });
                        tablecontainer.addListener(SWT.Resize, new Listener() {
                            @Override
                            public void handleEvent(Event e) {  
                                int contentY = table.getSize().y - tableheader.getSize().y-9;                                       // total height of the page. [ table ]
                                int contentX = table.getSize().x - vBar.getSize().x;
                                int windowY = tablecontainer.getSize().y - tableheader.getSize().y-9;   // total height of the window [ tablecontainer ]. 
                                int windowX = tablecontainer.getSize().x - vBar.getSize().x;
                                int locationY = vBar.getSelection() - tableheader.getSize().y;              // point where table is in window. 0 = top.
                                int locationX = hBar.getSelection();
                                int vPageEnd = contentY - windowY;
                                int hPageEnd = contentX - windowX;
                                vBar.setMaximum(contentY);
                                hBar.setMaximum(contentX);
                                if(vPageEnd>contentY){vBar.setThumb(vPageEnd - windowY);}else{vBar.setThumb(windowY);}
                                if(hPageEnd>contentX){hBar.setThumb(hPageEnd - windowX);}else{hBar.setThumb(windowX);}
                                if(locationY >= vPageEnd) {locationY = vPageEnd;}   
                                if(locationX >= hPageEnd) {locationX = hPageEnd;}
                                if(e.widget.equals(vBar)){table.setLocation(5,-locationY);}
                                else {table.setLocation(-locationX,tableheader.getSize().y);}
                                }
                            });
                        fontdialog.addListener(SWT.Resize, new Listener() {
                            @Override
                            public void handleEvent(Event e) {  

                                }
                            });     
                Button save = new Button(fontdialog, SWT.PUSH);
                save.setText(Parent.getResourceString("Save new settings"));
                save.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
                        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                            }
                        });             
                new Label(fontdialog, SWT.SHADOW_OUT); /* Filler */
                Button ok = new Button(fontdialog, SWT.PUSH);
                ok.setText(Parent.getResourceString("Done"));
                fontdialog.setDefaultButton(ok);
                ok.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
                            @Override
                            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {                  
                                    fontdialog.dispose();
                                  }
                                }); 
            fontdialog.pack();  
            fontdialog.setSize(display.getClientArea().width>>1,display.getClientArea().height>>1); 
            fontdialog.open();
            for(;!fontdialog.isDisposed();) {
                         if (!fontdialog.getDisplay().readAndDispatch())
                            fontdialog.getDisplay().sleep();
                        }   
        }
    }
```