# ScrolledComposite showing no scrollbars when set to expand

Tags: java, layout, swt, rcp

my problem is that if my Scrolled Composite has

```
scrolledWrapper.setExpandHorizontal(true);
scrolledWrapper.setExpandVertical(true);
```

it expands correctly on the whole ViewPart but if I shrink the View no scrollbars appear.

If I don't set the expand the scrollbars appear but the whole composite inside the scrolled composite dont expand.

```
    GridLayout gridLayout = new GridLayout(1, true);
    GridData gridData = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, false, false);

    ScrolledComposite scrolledWrapper = new ScrolledComposite(parent, SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL);
    scrolledWrapper.setLayout(gridLayout);
            // if set the scrollbars dont appear but the composite expand on the whole view
    scrolledWrapper.setExpandHorizontal(true);
    scrolledWrapper.setExpandVertical(true); 

    scrolledWrapper.setLayoutData(gridData);
    scrolledWrapper.setBackground(Display.getCurrent().getSystemColor(BG_COLOR));
```

Does someone know how I can set the Composite to expand onto my whole view but also show the scrollbars when the view is to shrinked?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scrollable Composite - auto resize - swt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14445580/scrollable-composite-auto-resize-swt)

Comment: Or this: [How to fill a ScrolledComposite?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17827535/how-to-fill-a-scrolledcomposite)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found a solution:

You need to set a min size. The composite needs to know at which size it's to small

```
scrolledWrapper.setMinSize(wrapper.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT));
```